# .SD and .SDcols for the i expression in data.table join

Tags: r, join, data.table

i'm trying to copy a subset of columns from  Y to X based on a join, where the subset of columns is dynamic

I can identify the columns quite easily: `names(Y)[grep("xxx", names(Y))]`
but when i try to use that code in the j expression, it just gives me the column names, not the values of the columns. the `.SD` and `.SDcols` gets pretty close, but they only apply to the `x expression`. I'm trying to do something like this:

`X[Y[names(Y)[grep("xxx", names(Y))] := .SD, .SDcols = names(Y)[grep("xxx", names(Y)), on=.(zzz)]`

is there an equivalent set of `.SD` and `.SDcols` constructs that apply to the `i expression`? Or, do I need to build up a string for the `j expression` and `eval` that string?

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example

Comment: btw `grep('xxx', names(Y), value = TRUE)` is a more direct way of `names(Y)[...]`

Comment: thanks for the tip @MichaelChirico!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps this will help you get started:

```
library(data.table)
X <- as.data.table(mtcars[1:5], keep.rownames = "id")
Y <- as.data.table(mtcars, keep.rownames = "id")
cols <- c("gear", "carb")

# copy cols from Y to X based on common "id":
X[Y, (cols) := mget(cols), on = "id"]
```

As Frank notes in his comment, it might be safer to prefix the column names with `i.` to ensure the assigned columns are indeed from `Y`:

```
X[Y, (cols) := mget(paste0("i.", cols)), on = "id"]
```

Comment: `mget` works like a charm. thanks @Frank and @docendo!