# Avoiding mget with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like to (dynamically and in place) bring some columns from one data table into another. I have the following code which gives the desired output:

```
# Set up example data
dt <- as.data.table(iris)[, rowid:=.I]
dt1 <- dt[, .(rowid, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)]
dt2 <- dt[, .(rowid, Species)]
cols <- c('Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width')

# Join the datasets
dt2[dt1, (cols):= mget(cols), on='rowid', verbose=T]
```

However, this is slow on my real data, and the output from `verbose` states: "'(m)get' found in j. ansvars being set to all columns. Use .SDcols or a single j=eval(macro) instead. Both will detect the columns used which is important for efficiency."

I've tried various forms of `.SDcols` and `eval`, but they all either give errors or give inappropriate output (e.g. columns contain the column name as a string). e.g.:

```
dt2[dt1, (cols):= .SD, .SDcols=cols, on='rowid', verbose=T]
dt2[dt1, (cols):= eval(quote("list(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)")), on='rowid', verbose=T]
dt2[dt1, (cols):= eval(parse(text="list(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)")), on='rowid', verbose=T]
```

NB. This question is similar to [.SD and .SDcols for the i expression in data.table join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43257664/sd-and-sdcols-for-the-i-expression-in-data-table-join) , however the accepted answer in that case is to use `mget`, and I'm trying to find an alternative to that which is more efficient.

Comment: Here is an option using .SD: `dt2[, (cols) := dt1[dt2, .SD, .SDcols = cols, on='rowid'], verbose=T]` but I am unsure about efficiency.

Comment: In this example, your `dt1` has *just* the columns you need (`cols` columns plus the `"rowid"`), so I can't help but think that this is over-engineering something that can be resolved with `dt2[dt1, on = .(rowid)]`. If there are other columns present (that you do not want to merge in), then `dt2[dt1[,c("rowid", cols), with=FALSE], on = .(rowid)]` seems to work well, too.

Comment: `quote("list(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)")` is incorrect use of `quote`, you need to remove inner `"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can one work fully generically in data.table in R with column names in variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833247/how-can-one-work-fully-generically-in-data-table-in-r-with-column-names-in-varia)

Comment: Also potentially helpful: [Assigning/Referencing a column name in data.table dynamically in i and j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60818053/assigning-referencing-a-column-name-in-data-table-dynamically-in-i-j-and-by/60818152#60818152)

Comment: Thank you for the comments (and yes, my real data has many more columns I don't want to include). The suggested other questions are both useful (in fact I'd already been through them both before asking) but neither give me something that I can use in this example (as far as I can tell).

Comment: @jangorecki Can you give an example on how to use `quote`, but use column names dynamically derived from the `cols` variable? I've tried many variations of this but can't figure out a way of doing it without typing them all out.

Comment: `quote` does not let you to make input dynamic, use `substitute` instead. Alternatively `as.call(lapply(c("list", cols), as.name))`.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I've tried variations of `dt2[dt1, (cols):= eval(as.call(lapply(c("list", cols), as.name))), on='rowid', verbose=T]` but just get the error: `object 'Sepal.Length' not found`.